# How do I do masking in PyTorch / Numpy with different dimensions?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I have a `mask` with a size of `torch.Size([20, 1, 199])` and a tensor, `reconstruct_output` and `inputs` both with a size of `torch.Size([20, 1, 161, 199])`.

I want to set `reconstruct_output` to `inputs` where the `mask` is `0`. I tried:

```
reconstruct_output[mask == 0] = inputs[mask == 0]
```

But I get an error:

```
IndexError: The shape of the mask [20, 1, 199] at index 2 does not match the shape of the indexed tensor [20, 1, 161, 199] at index 2
```

Comment: What behaviour are you looking for?

Comment: I want `reconstruct_output` to have the same values as `inputs` wherever `mask` is 0. But the mask is of a different dimension.

Comment: I got that part, I was asking how you want the mask to behave. Ignore a dimension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use [`advanced indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) here. To obtain the indexing arrays which we want to use to index both `reconstruct_output` and `inputs`, we need the indices along its axes where `m==0`. For that we can use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), and use the resulting indices to update `reconstruct_output` as:

```
m = mask == 0
i, _, l = np.where(m)
reconstruct_output[i, ..., l] = inputs[i, ..., l]
```

---

Here's a small example which I've checked with:

```
mask = np.random.randint(0,3, (2, 1, 4))
reconstruct_output = np.random.randint(0,10, (2, 1, 3, 4))
inputs = np.random.randint(0,10, (2, 1, 3, 4))
```

Giving for instance:

```
print(reconstruct_output)

array([[[[8, 9, 7, 2],
         [5, 4, 6, 1],
         [1, 4, 0, 3]]],


       [[[4, 3, 3, 4],
         [0, 9, 9, 7],
         [3, 4, 9, 3]]]])

print(inputs)

array([[[[7, 3, 9, 8],
         [3, 1, 0, 8],
         [0, 5, 4, 8]]],


       [[[3, 7, 5, 8],
         [2, 5, 3, 8],
         [3, 6, 7, 5]]]])
```

And the `mask`:

```
print(mask)

array([[[0, 1, 2, 1]],

       [[1, 0, 1, 0]]])
```

By using `np.where` to find the indices where there are zeroes in `mask` we get:

```
m = mask == 0
i, _, l = np.where(m)

i
# array([0, 1, 1])

l
# array([0, 1, 3])
```

Hence we'll be replacing the 0th column from the first 2D array and the 1st and 3rd from the second 2D array.

We can now use these arrays to replace along the corresponding axes indexing as:

```
reconstruct_output[i, ..., l] = inputs[i, ..., l]
```

Getting:

```
reconstruct_output

array([[[[7, 9, 7, 2],
         [3, 4, 6, 1],
         [0, 4, 0, 3]]],


       [[[4, 7, 3, 8],
         [0, 5, 9, 8],
         [3, 6, 9, 5]]]])
```